# How can I cache objects in a module using python3 c-api?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am implementing a container type using the python3 c-api.

Objects that are created should be put in a cache owned by the module. When objects are destructed they should be removed from the cache. The cache itself does not keep reference count on the cached objects.

I don't want to share objects between different interpreters, so the cache has to be owned by the loaded module instance. I thought I could put it in the module state struct, which could be reached via PyState_FindModule() and PyModule_GetState() when an object is destructed.

This solution doesn't work if a the module is reloaded by some reason.

Assume I create an object before the reload and put it in the cache found by the initial module state. I keep a reference to the created object, reload the module and then drop the reference. When the destructor runs it will get the new module state which will have a new cache, so I will fail to remove the object from the cache were it was inserted.